# Cannot change external column length

Tags: ssis

I have an SSIS package with a Data Flow that populates an Excel Destination from OLE DB Source. One of the columns in the DB has 500 characters length. On running the package, I get a warning:

> Warning: 0x802092A7 at Data Flow Task, Excel Destination [38]: Truncation may occur due to inserting data from data flow column "DT_WSTR_Description" with a length of 500 to database column "F6" with a length of 255.

I see that F6 external column does have length of 255. When I change it to 500, it becomes 255 again. How can I solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the Properties window for the Excel Destination, set `ValidateExternalMetadata` to false.  Then right-click on the Excel Destination, select Show Advanced Editor and go to the Input and Output Properties pane.  Expand the Excel Destination Input node and then do the same for the External Columns folder.  Go to the `F6` column and under Common Properties you can change the length of the column now without it reverting back.